# simple "T shaped" graph in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

Need draw a graph with dot/graphviz like this image:
[image: simple T shaped graph]

The texts can be above arrows, like graphviz does it. But how to achieve the T-layout? Need make a cluster for the top row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possibility using `rank=same` for a subgraph:

```
digraph g {
    node[shape=point, width=0.2];
    {
        rank=same;
        p1 -> n [label="text1"];
        n -> p2 [label="text2"];
    }
    n -> p3 [label="text3", dir=back];
    n[label="node", shape=rect, style=rounded];
}
```

You could also use a left-right layout instead of top-down.

An other possibility is to disable the effect of some edges using `constraint=false`:

```
digraph g {
    node[shape=point, width=0.2];
    p1 -> n [label="text1", constraint=false];
    n -> p2 [label="text2", constraint=false];
    n -> p3 [label="text3", dir=back];
    n[label="node", shape=rect, style=rounded];
}
```

The result is the same.

Comment: I must RTFM for the "constraint", but the 1st example is cool.. ;) TY.

Answer (score 2):

`dot` usually layouts trees in layers. To force an edge to not be a layer separation you can add the `constraint=false` option. So something like:

```
digraph {
  A [shape=point]
  B [shape=point]
  C [shape=point]
  N [label="node"]

  A -> N [label="text1", constraint=false]
  N -> B [label="text2", constraint=false]
  N -> C [label="text3", dir=back]
}
```

should work.

Note that the edge from the lower node to "node" has to be backwards, since `dot` layouts trees from top to bottom. Therefore the *logical* edge direction has to be from top to bottom, even though the *display direction* might be the other way round (which is the case here).